# How To Check if an Object is Instantiated?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, .net-2.0

I'm trying to list down all elements and attributes of an xml into two separate List objects.

I was able to get all the elements in the xml.
But when I tried to add the functionality to get all the attributes within each element, I always encounter `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

[image]
Please review my code below and advise where I'm not doing it right. Or is there any better way to accomplish this? Your comments and suggestions will be highly appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;

namespace TestGetElementsAndAttributes
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        List<string> _elementsCollection = new List<string>();
        List<string> _attributeCollection = new List<string>();

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            XmlDataDocument xmldoc = new XmlDataDocument();
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Test.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            xmldoc.Load(fs);

            XmlNode xmlnode = xmldoc.ChildNodes[1];

            AddNode(xmlnode);
        }

        private void AddNode(XmlNode inXmlNode)
        {
            try
            {
                if(inXmlNode.HasChildNodes)
                {
                    foreach (XmlNode childNode in inXmlNode.ChildNodes)
                    {
                        foreach(XmlAttribute attrib in childNode.Attributes)
                        {
                            _attributeCollection.Add(attrib.Name);
                        }

                        AddNode(childNode);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    _elementsCollection.Add(inXmlNode.ParentNode.Name);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.GetBaseException().ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Posting as well the sample XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<DocumentName1>
    <Product>
        <Material_Number>21004903</Material_Number> 
        <Description lang="EN">LYNX GIFT MUSIC 2012 1X3 UNITS</Description> 
        <Packaging_Material type="25">457</Packaging_Material> 
    </Product>
</DocumentName1>
```

Comment: make sure that you in childNode.Attributes has value not sure if it a problem but  <Material_Number>21004903</Material_Number>  does not seem to have atribute

Comment: Use the debugger to find out what variable is null.

Comment: (Don't forget to close your FileStream...)

Comment: I tried to check first using `childNode.Attributes.Count > 0` or `if(chaildNode !=null)` before the foreach. but it always go in the loop even the node has no `Attributes`

Comment: @yonan2236 - Attributes can be null (see my answer) I guess that behavior is according to the XML DOM specs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the existence of `childNode.Attributes` with something like this:

```
if (childNode.Attributes != null)
{
   foreach(XmlAttribute attrib in childNode.Attributes)
   {
    ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Great! I did not think about this : ). My checking was `if (childNode != null)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure childNode.Attributes has values, so add if statement prior

```
if (childNode.Attributes != null)
{
    foreach(XmlAttribute attrib in childNode.Attributes)
```